# Backbutton phonegap not work on mobile

Tags: java, android, cordova

I work with PhoneGap and I try to denied user from go page when using back button in mobile I search I found this code

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    var snd = new Media("/android_asset/www/sfx/lbl.ogg");
    snd.play();
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
}
```

Also I would like to run ogg music on enter the appliction but it's not work both of them not work.

Answer (score 0):

1.Android ogg files supported latest version only refer [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) confirm this ....

2.Change file format of audio file and run.

3.Then put your back key Listener inside ondeviceReady

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
```

and write function on for **onBackKeyDown**

Comment: should I use this   e.preventDefault();